# Create a constructor out of a constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

probably a dumb question but ...
...is it possible to create a constructor out of a constructor via Object.create().
Like in pseudocode:

```js
function f1(){this.val = 'test';}
var f2 = Object.create(f1);
var f3 = new f2();
```

Comment: No, it's not. What are you actually trying to do? Why do you need `f2` to be different from `f1`?

Comment: What would you expect `f3` to be like?

Comment: @Bergi: just out of curiosity ...

Comment: So `var f2 = f1` would solve your problem?

Comment: OK, if you're just curious I found a question with all the details you might want :-) If you need an actual problem to be solved, please comment and I'll reopen.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use `Object.create` - it creates an object, not a (constructor) function.

If you want to "extend" `f1`, you can use ES6 `class` syntax for that:

```
class f2 extends f1 {}
console.log(new f2) // works
console.log(f1.isPrototypeOf(f2)) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't clone a function using `Object.create` but you can do it by binding the function to an empty object, example below:

```js
function f1() {
  this.val = 'test';
}

var f2 = f1.bind({});

var f3 = new f2();
var f4 = new f2();

console.log(f3.val);
console.log(f4.val);

f3.val = 'not test';
f4.val = 'other value';

console.log(f3.val);
console.log(f4.val);
```

Answer (score 0):

The new constructor just has to call the old one and it has to inherit all prototypes:

```
 function f2() {
  f1.call(this); 
 }

 f2.prototype = Object.create(f1.prototype);
```

The same happens if you create a class f2 that extends f1.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling Object.create, you can have a function that returns a class (A class factory).  You would not call `new` to get your initial class though.  You would send in your parameters to the factory (instead of a `constructor`)

```js
function getClass(message) {
  class Foo {
    constructor() {
      console.log('constructed: ' + message);
    }
    ok() {
      console.log('ok')
    };
  }
  return Foo
}

const bar = new(getClass("yes sir!"))
bar.ok()
```